# Vector Notation with Tilda

Tags: notation, vectors

When I write my vector notation, does the tilde have to go below the pronumeral, or can it go above?
If so, how do I make it below on a google doc equation.
Thank you!

Comment: Standard [vector notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_notation) possibly uses arrows, but no tilde. So your question is unclear to me.

Comment: My VCE course taught that a tilde can be written below the vector variable.